# Contains operation for comparing elements in two lists

Tags: python, list

How can I compare two strings for contains operation? I tried using the **in** operator without success

```
list_1=['check value 1','check value 2']

list_2=['12312 check value 1 ','234 check value 2']

for ele in list_1:
    if ele in list_2:
        print 'element present'
    else:
        print 'abscent'
```

**Result**

```
abscent
abscent
```

I know we can compare them using another loop in list_2 and **in** over all elements. I am curious whether there is a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to test against *every element* in `list_2`; using membership on lists requires that the *whole* string is present in the list.

```
for partial in list_1:
    if any(partial in value for value in list_2):
        print 'element present'
    else:
        print 'absent'
```

Here the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), combined with a generator expression, at least *stops* searching as soon as a match has been found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works, but does **any** mean stop searching? I tried `if (partial in value for value in list_2)` and it returns **True** in every case even when the partial is not at all present in list_2. It would be great if you could give me some pointers to this.

Comment: @rahul88: No, `any()` will only ever return `True` if there is *a* value in the iterable passed in that is `True`. The default is to return `False` (if the iterable is empty).

Comment: @rahul88: the expression `partial in value for value in list_2` is a generator expression; it only produces values as you loop over it. Each iteration a test is done (`partial in value`). `any()` loops over the output from this expression one iteration at a time, looks at the next produced result, and if that is a true value it stops looping and returs `True`.

Comment: @rahul88: try my code with `list_2=['12312 check value','234 check value']`, leaving `list_1=['check value 1','check value 2']` as it was. It'll print `absent` twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martijn, just understood what you meant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code needed just a little change :-)

```
list_1=['check value 1','check value 2']

list_2=['12312 check value 1 ','234 check value 2']

for ele in list_1:
    for list2_ele in list_2:
        if ele in list2_ele:
            print 'element present'
        else:
            print 'absent'
```

You just needed the second for loop :-)